# @Selector not firing in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, inheritance, selector, subclass, uibarbuttonitem

**Context**

- The app is using a UINavigationController paradigm
- I have a class that subclasses 'UIViewController' called: **QuestionViewController**.
- I then have a viewController that subclasses QuestionViewController called: **QuestionMultipleChoiceViewController**
- In QuestionViewController I have a public method, called: **returnBarButtonItems** that returns an NSArray
- In QuestionMultipleChoiceViewController I set the self.toolbarItems property to the array returned by returnBarButtonItems
- The actions are in the super class - QuestionViewController

**Code**

*QuestionViewController:*

```
-(NSArray*)returnBarButtonItems
{
    self.facebookItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FacebookIcon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(facebookAction:)];
    self.leftarrow = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LeftArrowIcon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(leftAction:)];
    self.rightarrow = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RightArrowIcon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(rightAction:)];
    self.calcItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CalculatorIcon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(calculatorAction:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    self.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.facebookItem, flexibleSpace, self.leftarrow, flexibleSpace,flexibleSpace,flexibleSpace,flexibleSpace, self.rightarrow,flexibleSpace, self.calcItem, nil];

    return self.items;
}
```

*QuestionMultipleChoiceViewController:*

```
self.toolbarItems = [self returnBarButtonItems];
```

**Problem**

**The UIBarButtons get set correctly and are displayed, but the actions are not called on press.**

Comment: the problem is that you are assigning `nil` as the target, that means that the actions are being sent to `nil`

Comment: Got it. How come this works if I don't use a superclass?

Comment: Why don't you add this as the answer?

Comment: you should pass an instance of the class where those methods are declared, in general it will be self

Comment: This solved the problem, so please post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithImage:style:target:action:) of the function `initWithImage:style:target:action:` states that:

> *target*
>
> The object that receives the action message.
>
> *action*
>
> The action to send to target when this item is selected.

In your case you are assigning `nil` as the target, causing the action to sent to `nil`, that's why your method is not getting fired. Replace `nil` with `self` to correct the issue.

Comment: Using self as the target is probably the right choice, but that’s not at all what a nil target means. nil-targeted actions get sent to the first responder.